# How can I make 'CGFloat' conform to 'BinaryInteger' in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have a func called **test** which take input value that conform to `BinaryFloatingPoint`. In some case I have to feed `Int` type vale as well to the function, but Swift complain that it needs `Int` conform to `BinaryFloatingPoint`. So I tried to make `Int` conform to `BinaryFloatingPoint`, but I do not know if it is right way or how can I finish the extension in the way that Int conform to BinaryFloatingPoint.

---

**My Goal**: I want my function be able to handle **Numeric** but it is just not enough using Numeric as protocol! It does not work that way, it needs **BinaryFloatingPoint** to work! but from the other hand it cannot handle **Int**.

---

```
func test<T: Numeric>(value: ClosedRange<T>) {
   
    let someWork: CGFloat = CGFloat(value.upperBound - value.lowerBound)
    
}
```

**use case:**

```
let value: ClosedRange<Int> = -100...100
test(value: value)
```

**xCode error:**

```
Global function 'test(value:)' requires that 'Int' conform to 'BinaryFloatingPoint'
```

Comment: This is really weird. Even if you could make the conformance work, it would be semantically wrong. An integer (has no partial part, and has a fixed point) is precisely *not* a floating point number. It seems to me that your `test(value:)` function is il-defined. Perhaps your T should be constrained differently.

Comment: Exactly, that made me confused! `Int` has no floating point at first place! so why would Swift should be worry about it and making completion!? in other word! I can feed my input value with `CGFloat` but I cannot feed it with `Int`! Why not? it is much simpler with `Int`

Comment: "it is much simpler with `Int`". Yes, but _types_ do not work that way. If I have a function that accepts a [`CLLocationManager`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager) as a parameter, can I give it an `Int` instead, just because `Int` is "much simpler"? Of course not! `BinaryFloatingPoint` and `Int` are entirely different types.

Comment: @Sweeper Maybe he is trying to pass the value directly as a parameter but being generic the compiler has no clue which floating point he is trying to feed. The only way to circumvent that issue would be returning the generic type instead of void this way the type that would be set would define the input type when passed as ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral

Comment: If you need to put `Int` into your function, you most likely don't need the floating-point-specific members in `BinaryFloatingPoint`. Can you show what you are doing in `test`, so that we know exactly what members you need from `T`, and choose a protocol that has those members, and both `Int` conforms to and `BinaryFloatingPoint` inherits from?

Comment: @user you *asked* for that, when you defined your function as requiring a `T: BinaryFloatingPoint`

Comment: Is method overloading an option here?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here, with using **BinaryFloatingPoint** and **BinaryInteger** in deferent functions:

```
func test<T: BinaryFloatingPoint>(value: ClosedRange<T>) {
   
    let someWork: CGFloat = CGFloat(value.upperBound - value.lowerBound)
    
    print(someWork)
    
}

func test<T: BinaryInteger>(value: ClosedRange<T>) {

    let someWork: CGFloat = CGFloat(value.upperBound - value.lowerBound)

    print(someWork)

}
```